# .zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-snap_daily-2021-01-08-0525 is empty

Tags: zfs, snapshot

On my ZFS server `.zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-snap_daily-2021-01-08-0525` exists but it contains no files. The same goes for all `.zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-*`

How did that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are use accessing the dir though NFS?

The snapshots are mounted to those dirs and the content is not visible through NFS. It is, however, visible if you log into the server.